# 404 Could not find the controller

Tags: services, 8

I have a strange problem. This is my code:

```
function bd7_services_services_resources() {
  return array(
      'get' => array(
        'index' => array(
          'help' => 'Ritorna le immagini inserite.',
          'callback' => 'bd7_services_get_immagini',
          'access callback' => 'user_access',
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        ),

          'actions' => array (
            'immagini' =>
              array(
                'help' => 'Ritorna le immagini inserite.',
                'callback' => 'bd7_services_get_immagini',
                'access callback' => 'user_access',
                'access arguments' => array('access content'),
                'access arguments append' => FALSE,
              ),
          ),
          'operations' => array(
              // Define the index callback for a GET to /cart.
            'immagini2' =>
              array(
                'help' => 'Ritorna le immagini inserite.',
                'callback' => 'bd7_services_get_immagini',
                'access callback' => 'user_access',
                'access arguments' => array('access content'),
                'access arguments append' => FALSE,
              ),
          ),


      )


  );
}
```

If I call "rest/get" all works.

If I call "rest/get/immagini" I receive "404 Not found : Could not find the controller."

If I call "rest/get/immagini2" I receive "404 Not found : Could not find the controller."

Where is my error ? 
"rest" is my "Path to endpoint".

Thanks.

Comment: Enable service callback in service configuration

Comment: Rupesh: all "get" checkbox are checked in my configuration setting page.

Comment: You have to use a `POST` call to access your actions.

Answer (score 1):

I have also create custom resource using services module like:

```
function vintervals_resource() {
  $api = array(
'registration' => array( // Resource name 
'operations' => array(
    'create' => array(
    'help' => 'Ticket System',
    'file' => array(
        'type' => 'inc',
        'module' => 'My_module_name',
        'name' => 'includes/My_module_name.services',
    ),
    'callback' => 'My_custom_callback', // callback
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access arguments append' => FALSE,
    'args' => array(
        array(
        'name' => 'body', // parameter name in callback
        'type' => 'string',
        'description' => 'Function to perform',
        'source' => 'data',
        'optional' => FALSE,
        'default' => '0',
        ),
    ),
    ),
    ),
)
);
return $api;
}
   // callback
 function My_custom_callback($body)
 {
      // Your work here..
      $json_array = array($body);
      $json = json_encode($json_array);
      $body_Array = json_decode($json);
      $applicationId = $body_Array[0]->appno;
      $emailid = $body_Array[0]->emailid;
      $mobileNo = $body_Array[0]->mobno;
      $password = $body_Array[0]->userpwd;
      $returnArray = array('status'=>FALSE,'application_status'=>-1);
      return $returnArray;
 }
```

URL of my web service call is :

My domain + My endpoint + resourcename

"mydomain.com"+"api/ticketsystem"+"registration"

But it will not working directly in the browser.
For this I have sent post request to server with parameters and receive it in my callback then it's working perfectly.